# Is there an llvm function to find the set of live variables at each program point?

Tags: llvm, dataflow

I am writing an analysis pass for partially dead variables. For doing so I need the information about the live variables at a given program point. Is there an LLVM function that can return the set of live variables at a given program point? or do I have to write my own liveness analysis pass?

Searching for such function lead me to the documentation of isLiveIn() and isLiveOut() functions but I am not able to understand how do I use them. Also these function return a bool saying whether a reg is live or not but instead I need to know all set of registers/variables that are live at a program point. So it does not solve my problem either.

P:I am a newbie in writing llvm passes.

Comment: Dominators are what you want. A value is live in the parts of the function that it dominates.

Comment: I saw the domtree class in LLVM. It provides some functions to check whether a basic block edge or instruction dominates its use. You are right that if an instruction dominates its use, the corresponding variable is live. The thing is that I am looking for precisely the set of live variables at a program point. Which I can not get by using domtree class methods. But ya, what you said will be helpful when I have to implement the liveness analysis by my own.

Comment: You can — if a point is dominated by a value and dominates a user of that value, the value is live in the sense you want. As I understand it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick comments. If you can provide some examples or pseudo code or code then it would be a great help. According to what you said in the last comment, consider the entry basic block. It dominates all other basic blocks. It means that any value and its use is also dominated by the entry basic block. It means that at the "entry point" all variables are live according to what you said earlier. Which is not true. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: No. A value is live in block x if it dominates x and x dominates a user of the value.

Comment: I think now I understand what you are saying. Thank you.

Comment: **Question:** Find set of live values at the entry of a basic block x.
**pseudo-code:** Consider domtree. Iterate through all values that lie in ancestor basic blocks(in domtree) of x(excluding x). For a given value, check if all its uses lie within descendant basic block of x(including x) or not. If so then value is live at the entry of the basic block. 

_If I am wrong then please correct me._